# Comparison between two lists gives the wrong result when sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a piece of code in Python that compares two lists of numbers (one is generated by the computer with `random.sample()` and one is input by the user).

I need to know if the list of numbers the user input is the same to the list generated by the computer (regardless of the order of the members in each list).

So I got:

```
    if list_from_user.sort() == LIST_OF_NUMBERS.sort():
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

But regardless of the user's input, the `if` block always results in True and always prints "yes".
I run it in debug mode and when it reaches the `if` block it has two totally different numbers in each list, but the result of the `if` is still "yes".

If I remove the `.sort()` method from both lists in the `if` comparison, the `if` *does* produce the correct output, but the order of the members must be the same on both lists for it to be truth, which is what I'm trying to solve with the `.sort()`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `sorted(list_from_user) == sorted(LIST_OF_NUMBERS)`

Comment: *sigh* i knew i missed something stupid... thank you

Comment: Don't feel bad, it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, every variable is considered as Object.

`list_from_user` and `LIST_OF_NUMBERS` are two lists on which if the `.sort()` method is called, then it does not return a list. Instead it changes the original object list.

So `list_from_user.sort() == LIST_OF_NUMBERS.sort()`  will always return `True`, because basically it compares `None == None`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `.sort()` instead of returning a sorted list, it returns a value of `None` while sorting the list. I.e:

```
>>> a = [5,3,7]
>>> print(a.sort())
None
>>> print(a)
[3,5,7]
```

To fix this, use the sort before the comparison as the comparison returns `True` as both return `None`. E.g.:

```
import random

list_len = 5
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

LIST_OF_NUMBERS = random.sample(numbers, list_len)
list_from_user = [int(input()) for i in range(list_len)]

comp_nums.sort()
list_from_user.sort()

if list_from_user == LIST_OF_NUMBERS:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: this is actually something i dont want to do because i would like to keep the original order of the list the user input. i only need to sort them for the sake of the comparison. thanks for your answer.